# How to count the total number of splits opened in the current tab?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I want to detect the case when there is only one split in the current tab.

Answer (score 2):

Start with:

```
echo tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr(), '$')
```

`tabpagenr()` gives you the number of the current tab page.

Use `'$'` as the second param to `tabpagewinnr()` and that function will return the number of windows contained in the specified tab page.

So you can test for single window (no splits) with something like:

```
if tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr(), '$') == 1
    " do something
endif
```

Comment: This is cool! Let me try it!

Comment: I just asked another one as relating to my next step, could you help me too?

Comment: I answered with the first thing that occurred to me. If I had more time I might find something that just uses function calls but I'm a little short on time right now.